# Stacked bar chart showing labels in reverse in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart with labels in the middle of the bars.  For some reason, the labels are placed in the wrong position for the second column ("eIC").

Here's the code:

```
Role.Type=c("Other", "eIC", "eIC", "Manager", "eIC", "eIC", "Design", "eIC", "eIC", "Other", "Product", "Other", "Manager", "eIC", "eIC")
Role=c('Agile Coach', 'Android', 'Backend', 'Eng Manager', 'Data', 'Data Scientist', 'Design', 'iOS', 'ML', 'Operations', 'Product', 'Quality', 'Director', 'User Research', 'Web')
People=c(3, 3, 20, 11, 10, 7, 2, 2, 21, 1, 11, 3, 2, 2, 5)
df <- data.frame(Role.Type, Role, People)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(Role.Type, People)) +
       geom_col(aes(fill=Role), position='stack') +
       geom_text(aes(label=Role), size=3, position=position_stack(vjust=.5)) +
       scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, by=10)) +
       labs(title="Team Role Breakdown", y="People", x="Role Type")
g
```

And the result
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to put "fill = Role" in the first ggplot() function. This gives the plot you want with the text labels in the right positions:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(Role.Type, People, fill = Role)) +
  geom_col(position='stack') + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Role), size=3, position=position_stack(vjust=.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, by=10)) + 
  labs(title="Team Role Breakdown", y="People", x="Role Type")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to add total numbers on the top of each column?